# How to show navigation on map iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios6, mkmapview, mapkit

In my app i want to show the navigation based on two coordinates,currently i am using MKMapview to show the route.Is is possible to show navigation on MKMapview?

If so then how it can be implemented,suggest me with some example code.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In iOS 6.1 and earlier, you can't do that with `MKMapView`, but rather have to [Ask the Maps App to Display Directions](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/ProvidingDirections/ProvidingDirections.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH8-SW6).

Comment: I want to show this inside my app rather to open on Maps App.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In iOS 6.1 and earlier, the MapKit framework does not provide a mechanism to show directions on a `MKMapView`. Three options:

1. You can [request directions from the Maps App](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/ProvidingDirections/ProvidingDirections.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH8-SW6). It's an inelegant solution (to leave your app), but works.
2. You could consider using the [Google Maps SDK for iOS](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/), which provides an API for requesting directions. See the [Directions and the Google Maps iOS SDK](https://developers.google.com/live/shows/240588492-4001) video.
3. If you're a registered Apple developer, you should check out the MapKit framework enhancements in iOS 7. (Unfortunately, while it's in beta, we are precluded from discussing the details here.)